# Neo4j gem - Checking each object against a relationship effecient?

Tags: neo4j.rb

Just wanted an opinion on this in terms of design and efficiency.

Let's say you have a social network for liking music.

If you have query like `music.users` and out of those users you want to identify your friends. Visually you want to add a feature to identify these friends, maybe all your friends have a star on their profile and non friends are left alone.

Is it really inefficient/expensive to be checking each user to see if they are a friend? Alternate methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = music.users(:user)
              .optional(:friends, :friend)
              .where(neo_id: current_user.neo_id)
              .pluck(:user, is_friend: 'friend IS NOT NULL')
```

This would return an array of tuples: Each user from the association, and a boolean stating if they are friends of the current user

The `.optional(:friends, :friend)` is like calling `.friends(:friend)`, but is uses an `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead of a `MATCH` in cypher for querying the association.

For the `is_friend` part, that translates to `RETURN friend IS NOT NULL AS is_friend`.  Actually, since this is a `pluck`, the `AS` isn't necessary, so it could just be `.pluck(:user, 'friend IS NOT NULL')`.  Since it's doing an `OPTIONAL MATCH`, the `friend` variable in the query (which is the `current_user`) will only be there if the `user` from the result row is friends with the `current_user`.

One thing that you can do to help with understanding of what the query chain would do is to call `to_cypher` to see what query would be generated.  In this case, that would be:

```
puts music.users(:user)
          .optional(:friends, :friend)
          .where(neo_id: current_user.neo_id)
          .return(:user, is_friend: 'friend IS NOT NULL')
          .to_cypher
```

The `pluck` is a method that returns an array instead of a query chain object, so I replaced it with `return` in this case.

Comment: Also, this could be accomplished a bit better if we had eager loading, which is something that we want to implement soon

Comment: If you retrieve that user's friends, I can handle the logic in the view?. Because I'm thinking you will need to loop through each user, and do a check like `includes?` for every user against yourself, if true, then you can show the star.

Comment: Can you explain the query a bit. What does the optional `friend` do? I think I get the optional `friends` as we're seeing if that's a match. And what would `is_friend` be?